# Error Message: Cannot access class 'androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am making a QR Scanner app using Android Jetpack Compose.

The code is giving error message like:
Cannot access class 'androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Here is my build.gradle file for App Module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.plcoding.qrcodescannercompose"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    // Activity Compose
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:$compose_version"

    // CameraX
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.1.0-beta01"

    // Zxing
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
}
```

In case you want to see the code which is generating error:
[image]

Comment: You have a mess of imports, like in `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation` you're using compose version **1.0.5**, and `androidx.compose.ui:ui` has version **1.2.0-rc03** which [doesn't exists](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui) at all. All imports under `androidx.compose.*` should have the same version, equal to the one you've specified in `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion`.

Comment: Made some changes and all the errors are gone but still this one error exists: Cannot access class 'androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Please look into this

Comment: `androidx.activity` should be **1.4.0**

Comment: Hey @PhilipDukhov it's already 1.4.0.

Comment: but in your question sample code it's using `compose_version`